# generating from the Correlated Standard Uniform Geometric (CSUG) maximum distribution

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood, optimization

Suppose that $y_1,y_2,.....,y_N$ form a random sample from the CSUG maximum distribution (like order statistic but on a random number of observations, $N$) with unknown parameter $\theta$, where the pdf of each observation has the following form $f(y|\theta)=\frac{\theta}{(1-\theta)(1-y)^2}$ for $0\leq y\leq 1-\theta$ .

I want to estimate $\theta$ using maximum likelihood estimation. (I am working in R)

I begin to make maximum likelihood estimator of parameter in the CSUG maximum distribution

I have a problem: how can I generate a sample belonging to this max distribution?

Can I find the distribution of the maximum?

Comment: I think you need to give us more detail and emphasise the statistical part of your question as advice about R programming is off-topic here but available on other sites.

Comment: ok! i have random variable belong to  distribution call "the correlated standard uniform geometric " which have  pdf contain parameter theta i need to make maximum likelihood method in R to estimate theta

Comment: This is R coding question, must be closed as such

Comment: please edit to make your post clearer

Comment: I added some formatting, but you still need to clarify as noted by Glen_b. (Your question is not clear to me either)

Comment: I added a bit more clarification (I was mid-edit when @GeoMatt's edit was made, I hope I didn't lose anything essential from your edit). --- Mary, please add a full reference and some context, explaining more about the problem

Comment: I assume this is the paper your question arises from: Hao, Jie and Godbole, Anant (2016)  
"Distribution of the Maximum and Minimum of a Random Number of Bounded Random Variables"  
*Open Journal of Statistics*, Vol.06 No.02, 12 pages  
Article ID:65869,  
10.4236/ojs.2016.62023
... is that correct?

Comment: yes , it is . but I want use R code to estimation parameter by using MLE in R ! another Q how are you edit the post ?

Comment: @Glen_b I search of this problem , we can use inverse transformation metod to generating data hence the distribution become y=theta/theta.u where u is f(y) and use u<-runif(1000) in R but now how i can make MLE estimate in R ?

Comment: You edit a post by clicking "edit" at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.1302.pdf) seems to cover what you are interested in including parameter estimation.

If $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ is a sample from the CSUG distribution then the MLE of $\theta$ is $\hat{\theta}= 1 - y_{(n)}$ where $y_{(n)}$ is the max of the sample.

From your comments you want to use inverse transform. The necessary equations are below. From the histograms, it looks like this form of simulation resembles the pdf.

$$
\begin{align*}
f(y) &= \dfrac{\theta}{(1-\theta)(1-y)^2}\mathbf{1}\left\{0\leq y \leq 1-\theta\right\}\\
F(y) &= \begin{cases}
1 & y > 1-\theta\\
\dfrac{\theta y}{(1-\theta)(1-y)} & 0 \leq y \leq  1-\theta\\
0 &y<0
\end{cases}\\
F^{-1}(u) &= \dfrac{(1-\theta)u}{\theta + (1-\theta)u} \quad 0 \leq u \leq 1
\end{align*}
$$

```
## Simulate n values from the CSUG max distribution 
## using inverse transformation
rcsug2 <- function(n, theta){
  u <- runif(n)
  return((1-theta) * u / (theta + (1-theta) * u))
}

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
## theta 0.75
theta <- 0.75
y_seq <- seq(0,1-theta,length.out = 1000)

y <- rcsug2(1000, theta)
hist(y, prob=TRUE, ylim=c(0,10), 
     xlim=c(0,1),
     main=paste("theta=0.75","\n","theta_hat=",1-max(y)))

lines(y_seq,theta/((1-theta) * (1 - y_seq)^2) * (y_seq <= 1 - theta), lwd=2)

## theta 0.5
theta <- 0.5
y_seq <- seq(0,1-theta,length.out = 1000)

y <- rcsug2(1000, theta)
hist(y, prob=TRUE, ylim=c(0,10), 
     xlim=c(0,1),
     main=paste("theta=0.5","\n","theta_hat=",1-max(y)))

lines(y_seq,theta/((1-theta) * (1 - y_seq)^2) * (y_seq <= 1 - theta), lwd=2)

## theta 0.1
theta <- 0.1
y_seq <- seq(0,1-theta,length.out = 1000)

y <- rcsug2(1000, theta)
hist(y, prob=TRUE, ylim=c(0,10), 
     xlim=c(0,1),
     main=paste("theta=0.1","\n","theta_hat=",1-max(y)))

lines(y_seq,theta/((1-theta) * (1 - y_seq)^2) * (y_seq <= 1 - theta), lwd=2)
```

[image]

EDIT:

You can optimize the log-likelihood using `optim` or `optimize` by writing out the log-likelihood as a function. Note the function should just take in the `theta` value

```
neg.log.lik <- function(theta){
  n <- length(y)
  return(-n*log(theta) + n * log(1-theta) + sum(2*log(1-y)) - log(sapply(theta, function(x){ all(y >= 0 & y <= 1-x)})))
}
```

Here I specified the negative log-likelihood so I can use `optim` or `optimize` directly. The key to the function is checking whether the `y` values are within their specified range. You HAVE to include this because this is the only part of the log-likelihood that involves both the parameter and the data. Using `optim` you get

```
> y <- rcsug2(1000,0.5) 
> optim(0.1, neg.log.lik)
$par
[1] 0.5000271

$value
[1] -756.1681

$counts
function gradient 
      78       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

Warning message:
In optim(0.1, neg.log.lik) :
  one-dimensional optimization by Nelder-Mead is unreliable:
use "Brent" or optimize() directly
```

Heeding the warning message we can also try `optimize`

```
> optimize(neg.log.lik, c(0,1))
$minimum
[1] 0.4999542

$objective
[1] -755.8762
```

But I want to show you that YOU DO NOT NEED TO USE OPTIM in this case. Consider this simulation:

```
mle1 <- NULL
mle2 <- NULL
for(i in 1:10000){
  y <- rcsug2(1000,0.75) 
  mle1 <- c(mle1, 1-max(y))
  mle2 <- c(mle2,  optimize(neg.log.lik, c(0,1))$minimum)
}
```

The theoretically derived MLE looks exactly the same as the one obtained using `opimize`:

```
> summary(mle1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.7500  0.7501  0.7501  0.7502  0.7503  0.7518 
> summary(mle2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.7500  0.7500  0.7501  0.7502  0.7503  0.7518 

> par(mfrow=c(1,2))
> hist(mle1)
> hist(mle2)
```

[image]

But calculating the MLE using `optimize` takes CONSIDERABLY more time.

```
library(microbenchmark)
f1 <- function(){
  y <- rcsug2(10000,runif(1))
  1-max(y)
}
f2 <- function(){
  y <- rcsug2(10000,runif(1))
  optimize(neg.log.lik, c(0,1))$minimum
}
microbenchmark(f1,f2)
Unit: nanoseconds
 expr min lq  mean median uq  max neval
   f1   0  0  0.62      1  1    2   100
   f2   0  0 29.50      0  1 2550   100
```

That is 29.5/0.62 = 47.6 times faster

Comment: suppose that y1,y2,.....,yn from arandom sample from the CSUG maximum distribution (like order statistic but on random number N of obsrvation)with unkown theta .the pdf of each observation has the following form f(y|theta)=theta/(1-theta)(1-y)^2 for 0=<y=<1-theta . I want estimate theta by using maximum likelihood method in R

Comment: ok! i have this paper but i want to apply the estiamation part in R

Comment: the paper says that the MLE is $\hat{\theta} = 1 - y_{(n)}$ where $y_{(n)}$ is the maximum of your sample.

Comment: how i can produce this estimator of theta in R program ? first idea i have ,  I must generating sample belong to the distribution in problem , second I wil use MLE in R programme !! Are you have any idea about R programme?

Comment: See my edits, I hope I was able to address your questions.

Comment: I will read this carefully and collect some data to understand because I begin to use this programme recently , you seem very good in R . I will benefit from you . can help me alot to understand R for example book in R or facebook for you ?

Comment: I search of this problem , we can use inverse transformation metod to generating data hence the distribution become y=theta/theta.u where u is f(y) and use u<-runif(1000) in R but now how i can make MLE estimate in R ?

Comment: @Mary Note that bdeonovic already gave you the formula for the MLE in comments and then he edited his code to calculate the MLE of theta. It's all done already. Please spend a little effort to try to understand it.

Comment: @bdeonovic I write this code but there is no result rcsug=function(n=100,θ=0.75){
u=runif(100)
x=θ/(1-θ)u
result=x
list(x)
}

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, the code in your comments makes no sense. In my answer I have provided the code to draw samples from the CSUG distribution and I have shown you how to calculate the MLE based off a sample from the CSUG distribution.

Comment: @bdeonovic Im using inverse transformation to generate smuliation data, it seem I wearied with me

Comment: @MaryYousef I added code for simulating values using the inverse transformation. It looks like you had the wrong inverse. The histograms from this method look closer to the true PDF which makes me question my initial simulation code. So I would stick to the inverse transform code.

Comment: @bdeonovic    thanks   ,really I have mistake in inverse transformation ,I edit my code .now this point is clear for me but I will use optim to compute MLE
y=rcsug(n,theta)
log.like=function(theta,y){
L=nlog(theta)-nlog(1-theta)-sum(log(1-y)^2)
return(L)
}

out=optim(f=log.like,y=y,interval(0,1-theta),maximum=True) . this code is true ??

Comment: You don't need optim. Look at the black curves in my plots, those are the PDF. You see that they are monotonically increasing; the maximum will always be at $1-\theta$. Therefore, from a sample $y_1,\ldots,y_n$, with $0\leq y_i \leq 1- \theta$ the MLE is simply $1 - y_{(n)}$ where $y_{(n)}$ is the max.

Comment: @bdeonovic     please... can you explain for me how use optim code in this Q in R, i will take this technique

Comment: @MaryYousef I have added code to obtain MLE using `optim` or `optimize`. But again, its much more efficient to just calculate using the theoretical MLE. If you think this answer is sufficient please remember to check it as correct.

Comment: - log(sapply(theta, function(x){ all(y >= 0 & y <= 1-x)}))) please explain for me this code in neg.log.lik @bdeonovic

Comment: its the part of the pdf that is $\mathbf{1}\left\{0\leq y_i \leq 1-\theta\right\}$. The `sapply` must be used because `optim` and `optimize` want to be able to evaluate the log-likelihood on a vector of parameters

Comment: @bdeonovic oooh ! your method is faster !but this part we defined it when use c(0,1) in optim ?? can defined this interval without write it in log fun , another Q  WHY IN OUTput appear minimum (instead of maximum)?

Comment: 1) `c(0,1)` are the values that `theta` can take on. 2) The optimization functions in R give you the minimum value by default. So we used the negative log-likelihood. In this case the minimum of the negative log-likelihood is the maximum of the log-likelihood.